Is there any way to handle notifications in my flutter application without using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM), in all App's states?
I want to know if there any way to send notifications to my flutter application without having dependency on firebase. It should handle notifications in all states foreground, background or terminated.
I tried using Push Plugin and Flutter Push Notifications plugin, but both requires FCM for handling notifications in background and terminated states.
